# Is it possible to use Prometheus alerting in instant messaging such as Whatsapp or Telegram?

Tags: prometheus, whatsapp, prometheus-alertmanager, instant-messaging, exporter

My question is if we can use the alerts part of Prometheus to show them in Whatsapp or some kind of instant messaging.

Thank you very much from a newbie in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems there are a lot of projects to connect telegram, many docker based but none of them is just that easy to setup anyway. Just as an example

https://github.com/metalmatze/alertmanager-bot

Answer (score 1):

Telegram support just made it [into the alertmanager itself](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/pull/2827). The configuration part is already [documented](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#telegram_config).

Answer (score 0):

You ask about "some kind of instant messaging." Alert manager does not have a native integration for WhatsApp, but it does for the Slack instant messaging platform.

Info in the docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#slack_config